# pairs() plot of class variables

Tags: r, plot

I am wondering if it is possible to use pair plot (or such function `ggplot`) to plot pairs of a class variable, e.g.

```
#make some example data
dd<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(108),36,2),c(rep("A",24),rep("B",24),rep("C",24)))
colnames(dd) <- c("Predicted_value", "Actual_value", "State_CD")
```

I want to plot State_CD A vs B, A vs C and B vs C either just for Predicted_value or Actual-value or may be both on same plot.

I have 70 class variables instead of 3 in this example, and so don't want to change to wide format.  I'd prefer if I could plot them as class variable and keep their names such as A, B, C in this example.

Comment: You'll get more help if you tag this question with the name of the language and the environment you're working in. As it stands, I don't understand the question well enough to be able to tell if I can answer it or not.

Comment: It's not clear what you want: do you want to take all combinations of 2 classes from you set of 70 classes and then make a plot for each combination? That's going to be a hell of a lot of plots. Then for each combination you want to plot Predicted_value. Do you mean a boxplot or something? Or if you want both Predicted_value and Actual_Value, perhaps you want each plot for two classes to contain 2 'pairs' type plots in different colors? Can you clarify? Another option is that the observations for every class are in some order (and are thus related).

Answer (score 2):

```
ddbind <- do.call(cbind, split(dd, dd$State_CD)  )
pairs(ddbind[,grep("Pred", names(ddbind) )] )
pairs(ddbind[,grep("Act", names(ddbind) )] )
```

[image: pairsplot]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure why you need pairs here.  What about a small multiples approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot( dd, aes(Predicted_value,Actual_value) )
p + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~State_CD) + geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

[image: ggplot geom_point]

Reading through the question, if you've got 72 groups you're going to need to do some sort of summary operation and use a different type of plot. A dotplot of the means would be great for this

Dotplot:

```
dd<-data.frame(pred=rnorm(130),act=rnorm(130),state=rep(LETTERS,each=5) )
library(lattice)
library(plyr)
dd.m <- melt(dd)
dd.p <- ddply( dd.m, .(state, variable), function(x) mean(x$value) )
dd.p$color = c("red","blue")[as.integer(dd.p$variable)]
dotplot( dd.p$state ~ dd.p$V1, group= dd.p$variable )
```

[image: dotplot]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use ggplot but you can do something like this:

```
states = unique(dd$State_CD)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
for (i in 1:length(states)){
  if (i != length(states)){
    for(j in (i+1):length(states)){
      plot(dd$Predicted_value[which(dd$State_CD == states[i])],
           dd$Predicted_value[which(dd$State_CD == states[j])],
           xlab=paste(states[i]),ylab=paste(states[j]))
      }
   }
}
```

[image: plot]

This is not at all an elegant solution but it should work for you...